# Обращение к методу, который не реализован в интерфейсе

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface Animal {
    void eat();
    void sleep();
    void go();
}
```

Есть 2 класса животных (представлен 1):

```
public class Tiger implements Animal {
    private int x; //координаты нахождения
    private int y;

   public Tiger(int x, int y {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }

   @Override
   public void eat() {}

   @Override
   public void sleep() {}

   @Override
   public void go() {}

   public int getX() {
       return x;
   }

   public int getY() {
       return y;
   }
}
```

И класс `Locator`

```
public class Locator {
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Locator(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }

   public void find(Animal animal) {
       /**
        * Метод сравнивает координаты локатора и координаты животного.
        * Если координаты совпадают, выводится сообщение
        */
   }
}
```

Нужно в методе `find` класса `Locator` обратиться к `animal.getX()`.
Как это сделать, не *изменяя интерфейс* и не используя явное приведение типов `((Tiger)animal)`. И вообще, возможно ли это?

Comment: Нельзя менять интерфейс просто по условию задачи, или потому что он прекрасен сам по себе и вы не хотите тащить в него лишнее? Если второе, то можно сделать [посетителя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак. Возможно, стоит расширить интерфейс `Animal` или ввести новый, в котором будут предоставляться координаты животного.

Answer (score 1):

Отрефакторить и сделать Move Method для `getX` и `getY`. Если Вам нужно `getXXXX()` вызывать у `Animal`, значит эти методы должны быть именно там. А еще лучше перенести туда метод `find()`. Тогда полиморфизм будет реализован в полной мере.

Совет: Книга Рефакторинг Мартина вам в помощь! Очень полезная!