# Статическая типизация. Проблема с подклассами

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Название темы не совсем поясняет суть вопроса, но не знаю как сформулировать лучше.

Предположим на моём дереве могут расти и вишни и черешни. Но так как это два разных класса, то и поведение у них будет различаться. Предположим у них есть разные методы. Но не смотря на то, что у этих классов есть разные методы, их всё равно необходимо вызывать.

ООП, я понимаю хорошо, паттерны тоже.

Хочу услышать как лучше решать такие задачи в языках со статической типизацией следуя принципам ООП.

```
abstract class АЯгода {

}

class Вишня extends АЯгода {
    разбрызгиваетСвойСок() {}
}

class Черешня extends АЯгода {
    выстреливаетКосточкой() {}
}


class МоёДерево {
    private _ягода: АЯгода;

    constructor(ягода: АЯгода) {
        this._ягода = ягода;
    }

    get ягода(): АЯгода {
        return this._ягода
    }
}

let дерево = new МоёДерево(new Вишня());
if (дерево.ягода instanceof Вишня) {
    дерево.ягода.разбрызгиваетСвойСок();  # Здесь всегда будет ошибка.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ООП, я понимаю хорошо, паттерны тоже

Видимо недостаточно хорошо. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687613/106) уже задавали аналогичный вопрос. Ответ тоже аналогичный: в контракт `АЯгода` нужно добавить новое действие. А каждый подкласс будет имплементировать его по-своему. Например:

```
abstract class АЯгода {
    запустиСуперспособность();
}

class Вишня extends АЯгода {
    запустиСуперспособность() {
        // разбрызгивает свой сок
    }
}

class Черешня extends АЯгода {
    запустиСуперспособность() {
        // выстреливает косточкой
    }
}

let дерево = new МоёДерево(new Вишня());
дерево.ягода.запустиСуперспособность();
```

---

Другой вариант, раз уж вы начали проверять тип, это приводить поле `ягода` к подклассу:

```
if (дерево.ягода instanceof Вишня) {
    ((Вишня)дерево.ягода).разбрызгиваетСвойСок();
}
else if (дерево.ягода instanceof Черешня) {
    ((Черешня)дерево.ягода).выстреливаетКосточкой();
}
```

Однако такой подход противоречит ООП.

Comment: Что значит привести поле к подклассу? И чем противоречит ооп?

Comment: Про преобразование типов прояснил. Спасибо. Действительно можно преобразовывать общие типы к более конктретным и наоборот. А вот на счёт противоречий с ООП, непонятно.

Comment: @МистерФикс использование `instanceof` противоречит идее полиморфизма.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, про полиморфизм соглашусь с вами, для гибкой разработки лучше без этого.

Comment: @МистерФикс для любой разработки лучше без этого